# Учёт регистра значений при поиске с помощью linq выражений c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Есть Модель Client. Туда записывается вся контактная информация о клиенте. И например там есть поле логин. Так вот пользователь регистрируется и если логин который он ввёл уже существует, система скажет ему об этом. Но проблема в том что допустим его логин: Abc. И при попытки регистрации даже если ввести ABC или AbC  мой linq запрос всё равно его найдёт и скажет что такой уже существует. То есть он ищет не учитывая регистр. Вот мой запрос:

```
db.Clients.Where(i => i.Login == login).ToList();
```

Как сделать так, что бы при запросе учитывался регистр значения?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а сейчас не учитывается?

Comment: @tym32167 нет. То есть по факту в базе сейчас логин у пользователя abc. Регистрирую нового с логином ABC или AbC и т.д. и мне выдаёт сообщение что такой пользователь уже есть. Пример своего запроса я написал в вопросе, единственная разница что тут при проверке я пишу вот так вот `if(db.Clients.Where(i => i.Login == login).Count() > 0)` тогда выдаю сообщение.

Comment: а вот эта переменная `login` точно нигде не приводится к lowercase до того, как дело доходит до звпроса в БД?

Comment: @tym32167 привёл пример  скринов в вопросе.

Comment: хех, [тут пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3843060/312041), что в EF по умолчанию все нечувствительно к регистру

Comment: @tym32167 хех, привёл вам ту же ссылку в ответе iluxa ))

Answer (score 0):

Запрос, который вы сейчас привели ищет прямо в базе => проблему нужно решать на стороне СУБД.

Например, в MS SQL на уровне конкретной БД можно установить будет ли текст регистрочувствительным или нет.

Можно так же поменять сравнение у конкретного атрибута таблицы:

Проект=>[Выбираем нужный атрибут]=>Сортировка=>[Меняем параметры как душе угодно]

Comment: это ж логины, они вроде в asp.net по умолчанию к lowercase приводятся независимо от БД, если у юзера asp.net конечно

Comment: @tym32167, ну в вопросе не указано => не обязательно, что это какой-то веб-сайт. Мб какой-нибудь локальный сервис.

Comment: я просто на предыдущие вопросы автора глянул :)

Comment: @tym32167 это asp.net mvc вы правы.

Comment: @tym32167 а вы пишите что логины автоматом к lowercase приводятся? А как asp.net узнаёт что это логин? Просто по названию свойства? То что оно называется Login?

Comment: @Андрей нет, они приводятся только если использовать стандартные средства от asp.net для аутентификации. Скрины только вечером смогу глянуть, если не забуду

Comment: @tym32167 я тут кое что нагуглил. Действительно наверное iluxa был прав по поводу того что делаются изменения на сервере. Вот ссылка на ответ по такому же вопросу. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison

Comment: @tym32167 только там пример как изменить с помощью alter talbe а хотелось бы ещё найти как сделать такую же манипуляцию с помощью codefirst

Comment: @Андрей пфф, я то же самое нагуглил :)

Comment: @Андрей, ну тут через Fluent предлагают это делать: https://milinaudara.wordpress.com/2015/02/04/case-sensitive-search-using-entity-framework-with-custom-annotation/